# access 2003 query to remove the first chracter of a field into another field if it is the letter L

Tags: sql, ms-access

Exactly like my title states i need a query that removes the first chracter from [Parameter_Value] into [Parameter_Flag] if the first character is the letter L. Otherwise it remains unchanged. There are no blank values in [Parameter_Value] as they have already been removed.

i thought of a way . but it requires bring all the entires with L using the criteria Like"L*" into another table. and then removing the first characters of each field while adding an L to the [parameter_flag] column. usign the criteria NOT like "L*" to get the rest of the values in another table. and then combine the two.

Is there a more effiecient way?

[image]

Comment: hey! i made sure there were no other characters jsut upper case L. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm rusty on my Access (JET) SQL, but I think is what you want:

```
UPDATE table
SET Parameter_Flag = "L",
    Parameter_Value = MID(Parameter_value, 2)
WHERE Parameter_Value LIKE "L*"
```

Answer (score 2):

The `*` wildcard character only works in [ANSI-89 Query Mode](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/about-ansi-sql-query-mode-mdb-HP003070483.aspx?redir=0) ("traditional mode"). Perhaps safer to use `ALIKE`, which uses the same Standard wildcard characters regardless of Query Mode e.g.

```
UPDATE table
   SET Parameter_Flag = 'L',
       Parameter_Value = MID$(Parameter_value, 2)
 WHERE Parameter_Value ALIKE 'L%';
```